# Lead the way to this Literary Knight to its final “DESTINATION”

Tags: word, chess, word-ladder

As this Literary Knight (only chess move allowed) hops along, picks up a letter each time to make it to final

$DESTINATION$

Starting from a cell containing right D, ride the Knight picking up each successive letter on each hop to complete full journey.

You can get lost if you don’t take the right path.

Document the journey in chess notation

For example...A1, C2.......so on

[image]

In text form:

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
A  D S I O E S O D
B  E A N T I T N E
C  T E O D O S I N
D  I D N I T T D S
E  S S D S D N S A
F  E E I N E T E E
G  N T E E A I N E
H  D O N S I D I O
```

Comment: Can the knight be placed at the same place more than 1 time ?

Comment: As Knight journeys along, successive letters have to correspond to the exact order of letters in “DESTINATION”...otherwise it is on the wrong path..has to try another path.

Comment: Why "literary"?

Comment: I just wanted to bring out that it is more alphabets than Digits..Prime Knight is coming in the next one which will be bit more harder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### First to answer :)

This is the answer, here you go :)

> [image]

Method:

> Start from left corner D. Try every path possible till I reach a dead end. If all possibilities fail, go to next D. Saw some other users trying to backtrack and finding pairs and relations. That was an effective search method, but perhaps finding the relations took more time than an exhaustive search in this small case?

Comment: Great..how was it done

Comment: @Uvc added explanation. btw, i recommend you awarding the check later so as to grab more puzzlers' attention to your hard work :)

Comment: Sure....I will wait till at least tomorrow .

Comment: my method was rot13(gb tb onpxjneqf.  gurer jrer zhpu srjre snyfr genvyf gung jnl).  but on the other hand, I still wasn't fast enough!

Comment: @SteveV my method was: always keep the recently active tab open. check every new question. solve them if i can. :)

Answer (score 7):

I was not the first, but my answer is

> ```
>  D  E  S  T  I  N  A  T  I  O  N
>  H1 F2 E4 F6 H5 G7 E8 D6 B5 A7 C8
> ```
>
> Reasoning: A7 must be the O used because it is the only O that leads from an I to a N. I then worked backwards from there, along a <strike>unique</strike> path.

Edit: I later spotted **two** solutions:

> The first **E** can be either F2 or G3, so the **two** solutions are
>
> ```
>  D  E  S  T  I  N  A  T  I  O  N
>  H1 F2 E4 F6 H5 G7 E8 D6 B5 A7 C8
>  H1 G3 E4 F6 H5 G7 E8 D6 B5 A7 C8
> ```
>
> [image]
>
>  P.S. I arrived at my answer independently.

Comment: @Uvc were you expecting two paths to be found?

Comment: No..when I constructed it, I missed that..by blocking with another letter, I could have made it fully unique.

Comment: @Uvc I find it amazing that the check mark was given to the person who only found one solution, and who did not post the answer in the required chess notation.

Comment: Similar problems I have faced before...after consulting with editors, I have to be fair...if I didn’t ask for full details and didn’t ask for 2nd route, I have to go with one who answered first...regarding chess notation, once line is drawn, all possible move connections, that is good enough..I am as impartial Ivan be sticking to the spirit of the puzzle...I applaud you for finding the alternate route

Comment: Ah I see, but the check mark can go to the best answer, not necessarily the one who rushes to submit a poor solution first.

Comment: In one of earlier problems, I exactly faced opposite situation...editor has intervened and at his behest I had tor

Comment: I had to reverse...I can honor what the editor says..also, first solution provided was exactly what was asked for..another time at the suggestion of puzzle solver, I had to decide by coin toss...

Comment: Are you saying the editor intervened here? And that having stated the condition for an answer, you can say "I didn't mean that"? I did notice that the hasty answer not only flattered you, but assumed he would get the check mark, and made negative remarks about other answers. Not impressed.

Comment: Sorry..this is getting into personal realm...like I said we can submit to Mark Rubio for arbitration..will stand by his decision..I am relatively new..don’t know all the nuances

Comment: @Uvc I feel you may have badly misinterpreted something if you think that I told you that you must accept the first answer that meets the criteria. Our guidance is and always has been that which answer to accept is entirely at the asker's discretion; usually they pick the "best" answer, using whatever criteria they feel to be best. See in particular [How do we choose which answer to accept from a set of high quality answers](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1732) and its answers. For two equally good answers it seems most fair to award the first, but **quality should trump speed.**

Answer (score 6):

> The only O connected to both an I and an N is in square A7. Working backwards,

the correct path is

> H1, F2, E4, F6, H5, G7, E8, D6, B5, A7, C8.

Image:

> [image: solved image]

Comment: sorry, ninja'd you by 2 mins 45 seconds... good game! :)